Discord.js ephemeral Issue
I have this settings.js file that is running for the settings within a bot. The issue is that the message is displayed for everyone and not just one person, but I have the ephemeral: true at the start of the message. Am I missing something?
In the image you can tell it posted it for everyone.

const { getConfig, updateConfig } = require('../database/config');
const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle } = require('discord.js');

async function execute(interaction) {
    const guildId = interaction.guild.id;

    getConfig(guildId, async (err, guildConfig) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error fetching config:', err);
            return;
        }

        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has('ManageGuild')) {
            console.warn(`User ${interaction.member.user.tag} lacks permission to manage guild`);
            return;
        }

        const row1 = createMainSettingsRow(guildConfig);

        try {
            const message = await interaction.reply({
                content: 'Settings:',
                components: [row1],
                ephemeral: true,
                fetchReply: true
            });

            createCollector(interaction, message, guildConfig);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending initial settings message:', error);
        }
    });
}

async function handleMainSettings(interaction, guildConfig) {
    const row1 = createMainSettingsRow(guildConfig);

    try {
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Settings:',
            components: [row1],
            ephemeral: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating to main settings:', error);
    }
}

function createMainSettingsRow(guildConfig) {
    return new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('music_settings')
                .setLabel('Music Settings')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('invite_tracker_settings')
                .setLabel('Invite Tracker Settings')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('bot_settings')
                .setLabel('Bot Settings')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        );
}

function createBotSettingsRow(guildConfig) {
    return new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('change_prefix')
                .setLabel(`Change Prefix (${guildConfig.prefix})`)
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('add_bot_master')
                .setLabel('Add Bot Master')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('remove_bot_master')
                .setLabel('Remove Bot Master')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('back')
                .setLabel('Back')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        );
}

function createCollector(interaction, message, guildConfig) {
    const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 60000 });

    collector.on('collect', async i => {
        if (!i.isButton()) return;

        try {
            if (i.customId !== 'change_prefix') {
                await i.deferUpdate({ ephemeral: true });
            }

            switch (i.customId) {
                case 'music_settings':
                    return handleMusicSettings(i, guildConfig);
                case 'invite_tracker_settings':
                    return handleInviteTrackerSettings(i, guildConfig);
                case 'bot_settings':
                    return handleBotSettings(i, guildConfig);
                case 'toggle_music':
                    guildConfig.music_commands = !guildConfig.music_commands;
                    await updateConfig(i.guild.id, { music_commands: guildConfig.music_commands });
                    return updateMusicSettings(i, guildConfig);
                case 'toggle_invite_tracker':
                    guildConfig.invite_tracker = !guildConfig.invite_tracker;
                    await updateConfig(i.guild.id, { invite_tracker: guildConfig.invite_tracker });
                    return updateInviteTrackerSettings(i, guildConfig);
                case 'back':
                    return handleMainSettings(i, guildConfig);
                case 'change_prefix':
                    return showChangePrefixModal(i, guildConfig.prefix);
                case 'add_bot_master':
                    break;
                case 'remove_bot_master':
                    break;
                default:
                    console.warn(`Unhandled button interaction: ${i.customId}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error handling button interaction:', error);
            try {
                await i.followUp({ content: 'There was an error processing your request!', ephemeral: true });
            } catch (followUpError) {
                console.error('Error sending follow-up message:', followUpError);
            }
        }
    });

    collector.on('end', () => {
        const disabledRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('music_settings')
                    .setLabel('Music Settings')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                    .setDisabled(true),
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('invite_tracker_settings')
                    .setLabel('Invite Tracker Settings')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                    .setDisabled(true),
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('bot_settings')
                    .setLabel('Bot Settings')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                    .setDisabled(true)
            );
        message.edit({ components: [disabledRow], ephemeral: true }).catch(error => console.error('Error disabling buttons:', error));
    });
}

async function handleMusicSettings(interaction, guildConfig) {
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('toggle_music')
                .setLabel(`Music Commands: ${guildConfig.music_commands ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}`)
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('back')
                .setLabel('Back')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        );

    try {
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Music Settings:',
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating to Music settings:', error);
    }
}

async function updateMusicSettings(interaction, guildConfig) {
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('toggle_music')
                .setLabel(`Music Commands: ${guildConfig.music_commands ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}`)
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('back')
                .setLabel('Back')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        );

    try {
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Music Settings:',
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating Music settings:', error);
    }
}

async function handleInviteTrackerSettings(interaction, guildConfig) {
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('toggle_invite_tracker')
                .setLabel(`Invite Tracker: ${guildConfig.invite_tracker ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}`)
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('back')
                .setLabel('Back')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        );

    try {
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Invite Tracker Settings:',
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating to Invite Tracker settings:', error);
    }
}

async function updateInviteTrackerSettings(interaction, guildConfig) {
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('toggle_invite_tracker')
                .setLabel(`Invite Tracker: ${guildConfig.invite_tracker ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}`)
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('back')
                .setLabel('Back')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        );

    try {
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Invite Tracker Settings:',
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating Invite Tracker settings:', error);
    }
}

async function handleBotSettings(interaction, guildConfig) {
    const row = createBotSettingsRow(guildConfig);

    try {
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: 'Bot Settings:',
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating to Bot settings:', error);
    }
}

async function showChangePrefixModal(interaction, currentPrefix) {
    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('changePrefixModal')
        .setTitle('Change Prefix')
        .addComponents(
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
                new TextInputBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('new_prefix')
                    .setLabel('Enter new prefix')
                    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
                    .setPlaceholder(currentPrefix)
            )
        );

    try {
        await interaction.showModal(modal);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error showing prefix change modal:', error);
    }
}

async function handleModalSubmit(interaction) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'changePrefixModal') {
        const newPrefix = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('new_prefix');
        const guildId = interaction.guild.id;

        try {
            await updateConfig(guildId, { prefix: newPrefix });
            const guildConfig = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                getConfig(guildId, (err, config) => {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    else resolve(config);
                });
            });
            await interaction.deferUpdate();
            await handleBotSettings(interaction, guildConfig);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error saving new prefix:', error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error changing the prefix.', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    settings: {
        name: 'settings',
        description: 'Open the settings menu',
        execute: async (interaction) => execute(interaction),
        handleModalSubmit: async (interaction) => handleModalSubmit(interaction)
    }
};

I've tried setting this up multiple different ways and the same result, but or it errors out.

(I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment)
I can't spot any issue in your code. However, there is one thing that is unclear and this might help you spot the issue. Are you sure that the input being passed into the execute() function is indeed an interaction and not a message? You can only respond with an ephemeral response to an interaction (slash command, buttons, select menus, modals, etc).
